# Difference between glmnet and nnls for non-negative least squares in R

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, constrained-regression

I'm trying to do some non-negative linear regressions in R, and I found in the blog here https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/non-negative-least-squares/ that either the package `nnls` or `glmnet` could work. I tried both and found that their results differ a bit, so I'm wondering what are some differences between these two methods and whether one is more reliable than the other.

Comment: Look through posts tagged with [tag:constrained-regression]